# Why subclasses does not override the value of their superclass variable?

Tags: java

I have three classes as following, class b and c are extending class a. I am wondering why the code is not reading the value of b and c variables.

```
public class a{
  protected int myvalue = 1;

}

public class b extends a{
  private int myvalue = 2;
}

public class c extends a{
  private int myvalue = 3;
}
```

**body of my main method**

```
   ArrayList<a> myList= new ArrayList();
   myList.add(new b());
   myList.add(new c());

   for(int i =0;i<myList.size();i++)
        System.err.println("value is:" + myList.get(i).myvalue);
```

**output**

```
 1
 1
```

**[From Oracle website:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html)**

> Within a class, a field that has the same name as a field in the
>   superclass hides the superclass's field, even if their types are
>   different. Within the subclass, the field in the superclass cannot be
>   referenced by its simple name. Instead, the field must be accessed
>   through super, which is covered in the next section. Generally
>   speaking, we don't recommend hiding fields as it makes code difficult
>   to read.

Comment: -1 for non-compilable code. `myList(i)`? Come on, don't do this to us, don't be sloppy if you don't want us to be as well.

Comment: thats a typo man take it easy

Comment: But it won't compile. Just like the fact that you are accessing a private variable in your for loop.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I do not care what you would consider it but it was a typo.

Comment: @codeNinja it runs try it yourself, thats why I included the output :)

Comment: @codeNinja Presumably the `main` method is in `c` so it has visibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are shadowing your field `myvalue` and not overriding it, I believe something like this will do what you want

```
public class a{
  protected int myvalue = 1;
}

public class b extends a{
  public b() {
    myvalue = 2;
  }
}

public class c extends a{
  public c() {
    myvalue = 3;
  }
}
```

Also, please don't use [Raw Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html)

```
// ArrayList<a> mylist = new ArrayList();
ArrayList<a> mylist = new ArrayList<>(); // <a> on Java 5 and 6
```

Comment: great thanks, whats your idea about what I shared from Oracle website?

Comment: @JackMoore take a closer look at the bit from the tutorial: "**Within the subclass**, the field in the superclass cannot be referenced by its simple name." (emphasis mine).  When you're doing an external reference, the fields are not polymorphic.

Comment: @azurefrog it made me confused, as it says "Within a class, a field that has the same name as a field in the superclass hides the superclass's field, even if their types are different." AND then it says "Within the subclass, the field in the superclass cannot be referenced by its simple name"

Comment: Which is why they also say "Generally speaking, we don't recommend hiding fields..." ;-)

Comment: @azurefrog got it thanks, would you vote up the question. thanks